# Get the number of lines of code in a R script

Tags: r

I would like to know if there is a way to count the number of lines in a R script.

Ignoring lines of comment.

I didn't find a solution on the Internet. But maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this :

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
library(readr)

number_of_lines_of_code <- function(file_path){
 file <- readr::read_file(file_path)
 file_lines <- file %>% stringr::str_split("\n") 
 first_character_of_lines <- file_lines %>%
  lapply(function(line)stringr::str_replace_all(line," ",""))  %>% 
  lapply(function(line)stringr::str_sub(line,1,1)) %>%
  unlist
 sum(first_character_of_lines != "#" & first_character_of_lines != "\r")
}

number_of_lines_of_code("your/file/path.R")
```

Comment: It's almost like that. It didn't count empty lines. But it count comments lines.

Comment: I updated it i replaced `sum(first_character_of_lines != "#")` by `sum(first_character_of_lines != "#" & first_character_of_lines != "\r")`

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Example sctipt `tester.R` with 8 lines, one commented:

```
x <- 3
x+1

x+2

#x+4

x*x
```

Function to count lines without comments:

```
foo <- function(path) {
  rln <- read_lines(path)
  rln <- rln[-grep(x = trimws(rln) , pattern = '^#')]
  rln <- rln[ trimws(rln) != '']
  return(length(rln))
}
```

Test run:

```
> foo('tester.R')
[1] 7
```

Comment: Yes it works ! But is there a way not to count empty lines?

Comment: @celianou: After I uncommentd line in function, everything counted as you asked `> foo('tester.R')
[1] 4`

Comment: For current R version 4.0.5, `foo` requires `library(readr)` for the `read_lines` function.

Answer (score -1):

That doesn't seem like very useful information, but you can do this:

```
script <- "#assign
a <- 1

b <- 2
"

nrow(read.table(text = script, sep = "°"))
[1] 2
```

I use `°` as the separator, because it's an unlikely character in most R scripts. Adjust that as needed.

Of course, this could be done much more efficiently outside of R.

Comment: Maybe I should use another sep but I don't know which one. But it didn't work, it count every lines even the empty ones